# How to extend angular2 DatePipe

Tags: angular, typescript

Up to angular2.beta15 (including) the following code was working fine:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'isoDate'
})
export class ISODatePipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(isoDate: string, args: any[]): string {
    return super.transform(new Date(isoDate), args);
  }
}
```

On RC1 its not working anymore, even after I adjusted pipes syntax:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'isoDate'
})
export class ISODatePipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(isoDate: string, pattern?: string): string {
    const date = new Date(isoDate);
    return super.transform(date, pattern);
  }
}
```

The message i see in the browser is following: `The pipe 'isoDate' could not be found`.

If I remove the `extends` part and return some string - it works again.

What has changed?

P.S.

Currently changed it to

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'isoDate' })
export class ISODatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private datePipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe();

  transform(isoDate: string, pattern?: string): string {
    const date = new Date(isoDate);
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, pattern);
  }
}
```

It works, but looks a bit strange.

Comment: See https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/03/angular2-series-working-with-pipes/, you have to setup `@View` with the classname of the pipe, and you may have to tweak the case of the `@Pipe`'s `name` property value.

Comment: The article is written in September last year. The code i mentioned was working up to the release few weeks ago. Currently you could provide `pipes` in `@Component` decorator btw.

Comment: Alright, I saw your workaround. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with the Decorator somehow, though your workaround means I'm not bothered to check out the source.  A possibly related issue can be experienced if you extend an injectable.  If you use the decorator on the child class, inheritance doesn't seem to work properly, but if you let the child inherit the Injectability, everything is fine.

Comment: Note that as of RC-6 you must pass `_locale` to the DatePipe constructor.

Comment: Do you get any compilation errors? It might be that ISODatePipe fails to compile and hence `isoDate` is unknown

Answer (score 4):

*What has changed?*

Apparantely DatePipe class has now constructor

`constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private _locale: string) {}` 
so you can pass **LOCALE_ID** as parameter:

```
const datePipe = new DatePipe();
```

When you compile specifying local `ngc --locale=en-US` The LOCAL_ID get passed to the `DatePipe` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

extended DatePipe

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myDate',
})
export class MyDatePipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
    super(locale);
  }

  transform(value: any, format?: string, timezone?: string, locale?: string): string {
    const formattedDate = super.transform(value, format, timezone, locale);
    // do other formatting and return the value
  }
}
```

html

```
<div>{{ someDate | myDate: 'MMM d' }}</div>
```