# Display negative currency with parentheses in Angular 2 / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, localization

Angular's en-us localization has been updated since 1.3 to display negative currency with a negative sign instead of parentheses. I am using AngularJS 2 / Typescript and would like to override the default negative sign with parentheses (or even something else).

[Discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12870) on this shows to override negPre & negSuf however I do not see how to do this with Angular2.  Or maybe a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: Consider extending the CurrecyPipe class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032560/how-to-extend-angular2-datepipe

Comment: I want to keep other country/lang localization's intact and just update en-US. I'm looking at checking the localization in the CurrencyPipe and then if en-us alter the display, but just seems dirty.

Comment: this is my custom pipe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74575215/15104639

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I appreciate you asking this great question. Of course the currency pipe does exist, but after scanning the [currency pipe documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html) it seems that out-of-the-box this pipe won't do what you want. However, you can accomplish your goal with a custom pipe.

**1. First, recognize that you can "chain pipes".**

For example, you can have a number type variable, send it through the currency pipe, and then send it through your own custom pipe:

```
<h1>{{someNumber | currency:'USD':true | myCustomPipe}}</h1>
```

**2. Recognize that the currency pipe returns a string.**

This means that your custom pipe can accept a string, do some string manipulation, and return a new string.

**3. Recognize that the string manipulation algorithm to go from minus sign to parentheses isn't really that complicated.**

The logic can be interpreted in plan english like this, "If the first character of my input value is not a minus sign then just return the value, but if it is a minus sign then return the entire string without that first character and append a string of a single paren on either side of it". Using the JavaScript ternary operator it might look like this:

```
value.charAt(0) === '-' ?
'(' + value.substring(1, value.length) + ')' :
value;
```

I have also created a nice Pipe that does this as a minimum workable example. Suppose you have this component that is displaying the *someNumber* variable whose value is -5 (negative five).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>MinusSignToParens Pipe Demo</h2>
    <h1>{{someNumber | currency:'USD':true | minusSignToParens}}</h1>
  `
})
export class App implements OnInit {
   
  private someNumber = -5;
  
  constructor() {}
  
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And here is the code for the minusSignToParens pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'minusSignToParens'
})
export class MinusSignToParens implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        return value.charAt(0) === '-' ?
           '(' + value.substring(1, value.length) + ')' :
           value;
    }
}
```

Here is [the example in a Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/V39HFDs6yhh7DCvL9a2u?p=preview) if you wish to play around with it.

And remember, as [Migos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g2KKGgK-0w) would say, pipe it up!

Comment: Very clean, nice!  Thanks Jim.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Outstanding!  Thank you!

Comment: I have the value {{Details}} calculated in ts file,and displayed in html view with an ngIf when Details < 0...can i use a custom pipe and use in pipe or have to do anything in ts file too?